# Phalcon routing, how to set default parameters?

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

I'm trying to create dynamic routes in Phalcon `1.3.4`, but if a parameter is missing (like `:action` or `:params`) the route doesn't match.

Here is the (working) code :

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router(TRUE);
$group = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router\Group([
                                           'namespace' => 'App\\Backoffice',
                                           'controller' => 'Index',
                                       ]);

// All the routes start with /group
$group->setPrefix('/backoffice');

// Adding route to group
$group->add('', ['action' => 'index']); // matches /backoffice
$group->add('/:controller', ['controller' => 1]); // matches /backoffice/moderate
$group->add('/:controller/:action', ['controller' => 1, 'action' => 2]);
$group->add('/:controller/:action/:params', ['controller' => 1, 'action' => 2, 'params' => 3]);

$router->mount($group);
```

Is it possible to remove the redundant first three routes and only keep the fourth ? By assigning default values to match `/backoffice` or `/backoffice/moderate`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I initialize my router:

```
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);
$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);
$router->notFound([
    "module" => "page",
    "controller" => 'index',
    "action"     => 'index',
]);
```

There is also a setDefaults() method in the docs: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Router.html

Is this helpful?

Comment: This way we won't have a dynamic controller or action. The setDefaults() method doesn't help me either because I have several namespaces.